# Delete user files on logout

Tags: login, delete, users, user-profile

I have to setup Linux Ubuntu PC, on which when user logout himself, all files on his account have to be deleted, so when next time he logs in, he will have environment like he is never been logged before.

Can you help me how to achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try Gofris.

> Gofris is an open source program that allows Ubuntu users to lock their Home folder. You can compare it to the Deep Freeze software on Windows. What is special in Gofris is that once enabled, any changes performed in your Home folder will be discarded after system rebooting. So, it is recommended for public computers (Internet café, for example).

References:

[Launchpad for the project](https://launchpad.net/gofris)

[Tutorial for setting it up on 11.04](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/07/install-gofris-on-ubuntu-1104-to.html)